# C++ Move vs Copy a local stl container to a list inside a loop

Tags: copy, containers, c++17, move

In the lower fictitious code example (C++17) I ask myself whether I should optimize here with std::move or better not. The last emplace_back seems to be a suitable candidate, since "idsLocal" is certainly no longer needed afterwards. With the first emplace_back I wonder if that would make sense here. If I move "idsLocal" there and call the clear() afterwards, I avoid the copy, but I am feared that "idsLocal" would potentially have to reallocate multiple times again in the next iterations (memory is moved?!), which it probably wouldn't have done otherwise because of the reserve-call. So would I have an advantage here (and why) if I use std::move *everywhere* in the emplace_back-calls? My time measurements were very fluctuating and did not really give a clear result for me.

For example, let's take the following input data for divideIntoIdsList:

```
=> "limit" is 1024 and we have 5120 different id's
```

Naively thought, the following could come out:

```
Without move in the FIRST emplace_back:
    -> 1  malloc(s) for the reserve at idsLocal
    -> 5  malloc(s) for copying idsLocal 5 times in idsList

With move in the FIRST emplace_back:
    -> 1  malloc(s) for the reserve at idsLocal
    -> 0  malloc(s) for moving idsLocal 5 times in idsList (?)
    -> 40 malloc(s) for dynamic resizes in idsLocal beginning 
                    after the first move (4 x 10 push_back's per limit) (?)
```

Assuming that allocations are expensive, would the
move variant be even slower?

**Code-Example:**

```
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template < class T >
auto divideIntoIdsList( size_t limit, const T &ids, std::list< T > &idsList )
{
  if ( ids.empty() )
    return;

  T idsLocal;
  idsLocal.reserve( limit );
  size_t iIdCount=0;

  for( typename T::const_iterator itIds = ids.begin();
       itIds != ids.end(); ++itIds )
  {
    idsLocal.push_back( *itIds );

    if( ++iIdCount == limit )
    {
        idsList.emplace_back( idsLocal ); //std::move(idsLocal) here?!
        idsLocal.clear();
        iIdCount=0;
    }
  }

  if( iIdCount > 0 )
      idsList.emplace_back( idsLocal ); //std::move(idsLocal) here seems useful
}

int main()
{
    using ids_t = std::vector< size_t >;
    ids_t ids( 5120 );
    std::iota( std::begin( ids ), std::end( ids ), 0 );
    std::list< ids_t > idslist;
    divideIntoIdsList( 1024, ids, idslist );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You worry about optimisation and yet emplace elements one-by-one in a loop, instead of using a constructor that takes a range?

Comment: I can of course write a better routine, but that is not the question here. I want to know exactly how it behaves in this fictitious code example. My intention is to find out if it generally makes sense to always use move where it is possible or if there are scenarios where it should not be used.

Comment: About the same number of allocations would happen either way. If you move from `idsLocal`, `emplace_back` would take memory from `idsLocal`, which would end up empty and would have to allocate on the next iteration. If you copy from `idsLocal`, that copy would have to allocate memory. At the end of the day, you have a list of `N` vectors, each controlling some chunk of memory; so there have to be `N` allocations one way or another.

Comment: As to `reserve` - you can just call `reserve` again right after `clear`.

Comment: Yes. But is the code slower (dynamic resizing) when ONLY adding the std::move? This type of code I saw in production code and people we're blindly adding std::move at all places where they can and thinking a move is never slower than no move without looking at the context. Are they right?